# Calculating Quarter (Q1, Q2, etc) using Date field in ArcMap Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, field-calculator, date

I am using ArcMap 10.0 and making a map where I symbolize on annual quarter (i.e. Q1 2013, Q2 2013, and so on by quarter through 2015).

If a date field contains this: 01/15/2013, and I wanted to create a new field called QUARTER, that would contain the quarter in which the date falls, how could I do that?

Right now I'm just definition querying a range of dates, but surely there is a way to just calculate Quarter, right?

Comment: Is the date field text or date field type?

Answer (score 7):

This python field calculator script should work:

```
def checkValue(field):
  myMonth = int(field.split('/')[0])
  myYear = field.split('/')[2]
  if myMonth <=3:
    return 'Q1-' + myYear
  elif myMonth >= 4 and myMonth <=6:
    return 'Q2-' + myYear
  elif myMonth >=7 and myMonth <=9:
    return 'Q3-' + myYear
  else:
    return 'Q4-' + myYear
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: You could simplify that a bit further by using `if myMonth <=3:  elif myMonth <=6:  elif myMonth <=9:  else:`

Comment: @kenbuja, Good point!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406131/737471) using [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/737471):

```
def checkValue(field):
    m,d,y=field.split('/') #assumes date in some backward MM/DD/YYYY format, what's with that? ;)
    q=(int(m)-1)//3 + 1
    return 'Q%s - %s'%(q,y)
```

Comment: `mmddyyy` is not defined here.